# Get the request body in play framework using filters and actions.(in java)

Tags: java, playframework

Not able to find request body for incoming request in play framework java.
I need to log all the incoming request in play framework api. For that, I try to use filters and action compositions. But I am able to get the request body.

I try to use filters and action compositions.

```
public class LoggingFilter extends EssentialFilter {

    private final Executor executor;

    @Inject
    public LoggingFilter(Executor executor) {
        super();
        this.executor = executor;
    }

    @Override
    public EssentialAction apply(EssentialAction next) {
        return EssentialAction.of(request -> {
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

            Accumulator<ByteString, Result> accumulator = next.apply(request);

            System.out.println(request);
            return accumulator.map(result -> {
                long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                long requestTime = endTime - startTime;


                Logger.info("{} {} took {}ms and returned {}",
                        request.method(), request.uri(), requestTime, result.status());

                return result.withHeader("Request-Time", "" + requestTime);
            }, executor);
        });
    }
}
```

From this request, I am just able to get boolean whether body is present or not. But not able to get the actual body.

Answer (score 0):

You can get request body and log it as you want in action composition:

```
import play.Logger;
import play.mvc.Http;
import play.mvc.Result;

import java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage;

public class ClientLogger extends play.mvc.Action.Simple {

    public CompletionStage<Result> call(Http.Context context) {
        StringBuffer logMessage = new StringBuffer();
        logMessage.append(context.request().toString())
                .append("\n")
                .append("body json: " + context.request().body().asJson().toString());
        Logger.info(logMessage.toString());
        return delegate.call(context);
    }
}
```